# How to search on Jira for all subtasks where parents meet criteria

Tags: jira, jql

I have a filter on Jira to display only tasks with a certain label. However a lot of these tasks have subtasks, is it possible to display the all of the subtasks from parents with the label?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get [Scriptrunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) for Jira add-on to achieve this result.

If you are on Jira Server, the query would be:

```
issueFunction in subtasksOf("label = xxx")
```

If you are on Jira Cloud, run the same query in ScriptRunner Enhanced Search window.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't think Scriptrunner is an option, as it is a customer organisation's Jira project I am connecting to, which does not have Scriptrunner installed.